# Test a REST get request

Tags: rest, phpunit, slim

How do I **test a GET request** of a REST API with PHPUnit 4.1? I use the Slim PHP-Framework and could manage to test the **response code but not the body or header**.
This is what I have so far:

TestClass:

```
class AssetTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

public function request($method, $path, $options = array())
{
    // Capture STDOUT
    ob_start();

    // Prepare a mock environment
    Environment::mock(array_merge(array(
        'REQUEST_METHOD' => $method,
        'PATH_INFO' => $path,
        'SERVER_NAME' => 'slim-test.dev',
    ), $options));

    $app = new \Slim\Slim();
    $this->app = $app;
    $this->request = $app->request();
    $this->response = $app->response();

    // Return STDOUT
    return ob_get_clean();
}

   public function get($path, $options = array()){
      $this->request('GET', $path, $options);
   }

   public function testGetAssets(){
      $this->get('/asset');
      $this->assertEquals('200', $this->response->status());
   }
}
```

If my JSON response of http://example.com/asset looks like this (Code 200):

```
[
  {
    "AssetID": "4b0be88b9e853",
    "AssetStatusID": "1"
  }
]
```

Comment: You sure you are doing Unit testing? It's about testing units, not functionality. In this case, you might want to test your action function(The `$actionMethod` in your `$app->get('\some\url', $actionMethod)`. Functional testing of REST APIs can and should be done manually, since there are no very good automatic tools. But you can try something like SoapUI.

Comment: Ok, so you mean testing the model function which e.g. makes the database query?

Comment: yep, that would be a good start. If you have some middleware, you can test that too.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is good. To get the body of response just call the
`$response->getBody()` and use `json_decode` to decode this response. To get the header call the `$response->getHeaders()`.

In your case it will by `$this->response->getBody()`. So your test 
method will be look like this

```
public function testGetAssets(){
        $this->get('/asset');
        $response = json_decode($this->response->getBody(), true); //response body
        $headers = $this->response->getHeaders()  //response headers
        $this->assertEquals('200', $this->response->status());
    }
```

This answer is respect to the latest version of guzzlehttp i.e. 6.0